# How do i animate a view in React Native that adjusts height to its content?

Tags: react-native, react-animated

I have a view that contains a flatlist, and for now it just adjusts to its content due to the "maxHeight" that i defined, but without animation.

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

I tried this code to animate the height:

```
const [searchBoxHeight, setSearchBoxHeight] = useState(0);
const animatedSearchBoxHeight = useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current;

 useEffect(() => {
    Animated.timing(animatedSearchBoxHeight, {
      toValue: searchBoxHeight,
      duration: 300,
      useNativeDriver: false,
    }).start();
  }, [searchBoxHeight]);

<Animated.View style={{ height: animatedSearchBoxHeight }}>
    <View
      style={styles.searchBox}
      onLayout={(event) => {
        setSearchBoxHeight(event.nativeEvent.layout.height);
      }}
    >
      <FlatList
        nestedScrollEnabled
        showsVerticalScrollIndicator
        data={getCetaceansFiltered()}
        keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
        renderItem={renderItem}
        ItemSeparatorComponent={() => (
          <ListItemSeparator
            width="95%"
            color={defaultStyles.colors.transparent}
          />
        )}
      />
    </View>
 </Animated.View>

searchBox: {
    paddingVertical: 12,
    width: "100%",
    backgroundColor: defaultStyles.colors.transparent,
    borderRadius: 20,
    marginTop: 5,
    maxHeight: 250,
  },
```

But i got this in the app:

[image: 3]